# Express Controller Modularity

Tags: node.js, express

New to Node/Express, trying to figure out what the best way to make my server controllers organized and modular. I have app.js file with the following code.

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();

// Launch Server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8888;

app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log('Server running on port ' + PORT + '!');
});

// Render Static Views from the Public Directory/Views
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public/views/'));

// API
// var foo = require(bar);
```

I want to keep all of my API logic in apiController.js then require it into my app.js. What's the best way to do this?

Example GET Endpoint

```
app.get('/api', function(req, res) {
  res.json({
    success: true,
    message: 'Hello World!'
  });
});
```

Here is my project structure: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like David Fang's solution, but I would go one step further and create an Express 4 router for your API routes. They're very composable and modular, as they can act as both routers and middleware, can be nested and imported neatly.

app.js

```
var apiRouter = require('./controllers/apiController.js');
app.use('/api', apiRouter);
```

apiController.js

```
var express = require('express');
var apiRouter = express.Router();

apirouter.get('/some/route', (req, res) => {
    // some code...
})

module.exports = apiRouter;
```

Documentation: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router

Comment: Nice. I really like this method. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's more like a "modular" method. Just remember that don't get confused by `/api/some/route` and `/some/route`.

Comment: Thanks David. I appreciate your responses.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple method:

app.js

```
require('./controllers/apiController.js')(app);
```

apiController.js

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/api/some/route', function(req, res) {
        // some code...
    }
}
```

Maybe this is not the best approach, but I have used it without problem in small apps.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i do it

I have `app/controllers/index` which call register method each of the controller. Each controller has a register method that register its route with the app.

In controllers:

```
exports.register = function(app) {
    app.post('/login', login)
}
```

In controllers index.js or routes or whatever you want to name it.

```
require('../controllers/auth').register(app)
require('../controllers/registration').register(app)
```

and at the end, drops all other routes to 404.